# how to put a br tag after every set of new data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There I have six buttons and an add button when I click any of the buttons and click on the add button I get their value so if I click the first button and the third button and click add I will get the first and the third button's value. But when I try again and let say I click the second and fifth button then click add I get there value's button they get connected to the last values that were there before I want it to give two br tags then show the values

here's my code

```js
var valArray = [];
      $('button').click(function() {
        if (valArray.indexOf(this.value) === -1) {
          valArray.push(this.value);
          return false;
        }
      });

      $('.add').click(function() {
        $("#values").html(valArray + "&nbsp;");

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='linux'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
linux
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='apple'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
apple
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='windows'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
windows
</button>




<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='chrome'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
chrome
</button>



<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='netscape'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
netscape
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='github'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
github
</button>




<button type="button" id="addButton" class="add">Add</button>


<div id="values">


      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should empty your valArray when you've added to the Value div. This means any new values will be separate.

```js
var valArray = [];
      $('button').click(function() {
        if (valArray.indexOf(this.value) === -1) {
          valArray.push(this.value);
          return false;
        }
      });

      $('.add').click(function() {
        var valueText = $("#values").html();
        console.log(valueText);
        $("#values").html(valueText + valArray + "<br><br>");
        valArray = [];
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='linux'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
linux
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='apple'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
apple
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='windows'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
windows
</button>




<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='chrome'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
chrome
</button>



<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='netscape'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
netscape
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='github'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
github
</button>




<button type="button" id="addButton" class="add">Add</button>


<div id="values">


      </div>
```

Comment: hello @simonR thank you very much for this code works very nice

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
$('.add').click(function() {
        $("#values").html(valArray + "&nbsp;");
      });
```

To :

```
$('.add').click(function() {
            $("#values").html($("#values").html() + valArray + "</br></br>");
            valArray =[];
          });
```

Result :

```js
var valArray = [];
      $('button').click(function() {
        if (valArray.indexOf(this.value) === -1) {
          valArray.push(this.value);
          return false;
        }
      });

      $('.add').click(function() {
        $("#values").html($("#values").html() + valArray + "</br></br>");
        valArray =[];
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='linux'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
linux
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='apple'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
apple
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='windows'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
windows
</button>




<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='chrome'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
chrome
</button>



<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='netscape'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
netscape
</button>

<button type='submit' class='checkBtn' name='checkBtn' id='checkBtn' value='github'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
github
</button>




<button type="button" id="addButton" class="add">Add</button>


<div id="values">


      </div>
```